# Is there a Tree class and Node class in Objective-C or Cocoa-Touch?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, tree

The `CFTree` is actually mentioned in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFCollections/Articles/types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001129-CJBEJBHH) as

> You use trees—objects of the CFTree type—to represent nodes in hierarchically organized structures

But [CFTree reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTreeRef/Reference/reference.html) actually shows that it is OO, but is it C++ and not Objective-C?Is there a class for Tree and Node, in Objective-C, Cocoa, or a common and reliable one (maybe an open source one), or maybe a set of Objective-C wrappers around `CFTree`?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use NSArrays of NSArrays